# Add watched object to array - Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am in middle of vue application.
The problem I am facing is that I want to add only the changed/unique object to the new array.

It keeps on adding repeated objects. I am sure it's some kind of silly mistake on my side, but I can't seem to find it.

```
<script>   
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      changedArray: [],
      originalArray: [
         {key1:val1},
         {key1:val2},
         {key1:val3}
      ]
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.originalArray.forEach((val) => {
      this.$watch(() => val, this.handleChange, { deep: true });
    });
  },
  methods: {
    handleChange(newVal) {
      if (this.changedArray.length > 0) {
        this.changedArray.forEach((o) => {
          if (o.key1 !== newVal.key1) {
            this.changedArray.push(newVal)
          }
      });
      } else {
        this.changedArray.push(newVal)
      }
    },
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

VueJS can have some issues with the reactivity of deep watching objects inside arrays like this.

First of all, consider if you can remove the need to use a watcher. In most cases, watching an object is not necessary and can be avoided by changing the structure of the program.

This is preferred as it reduces component complexity and keeps things clear. Similarly, watchers can be computationally complex for vue, especially when they are deep.

In your example, you are creating a watcher for each item of an array. This could become incredibly detrimental to your performance

Is there any way you can refactor so that the method that is responsible for updating each of the individual objects also runs the `handleChange` comparison? That way no watcher is required.

If you must use this approach, you will need to separate your logic by creating a child component that houses the watcher logic.

That way instead of looping over each object in the parent component and creating a watcher, the `v-for` in the parent component creates instances of the child component.

The child component then creates a watcher for itself only, and emits an event to the parent when it is updated.